# Folders of pictures into a single PDF

Tags: python, bash, pdf-generation, png, jpeg

I have the following problem.

I have folder structure like this:

```
vol1/
     chap1/
          01.jpg
          02.JPG
          03.JPG
     chap2/
          04.JPG
          05.jpg
          06.jpg
     chap3/
          07.JPG
          08.jpg
          09.JPG
vol2/
     chap4/
          01.JPG
          02.jpg
          03.jpg
     chap5/
          04.jpg
          05.JPG
          06.jpg
     chap6/
          07.jpg
          08.JPG
          09.jpg
```

Inside a single `vol` folder, the chapters have an increasing order, and the same happens for the jpg files inside each `chap` folder.

Now, I would like, for each `vol` folder to obtain a pdf, maintaining the ordering of the pictures. Think about it as a divided comics or manga volume to be put back into a single file.

How could I do it in bash or python?
I do not know how many volumes I have, or how many chapters are in a single volume, or how many jpg files are in a single chapter. In other words, I need it to work it for whatever number of volumes/chapters/jpgs.

An addition would be considering heterogeneous picture files, maybe having both jpg and png in a single chapter, but that's a plus.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work like intended ! Tell me if you encounter issues

```
import os
from PIL import Image

def merge_into_pdf(paths, name):
    list_image = []
    # Create list of images from list of path
    for i in paths:
        list_image.append(Image.open(i).convert("RGB"))
    # merge into one pdf
    if len(list_image) == 0:
        return
    # get first element of list and pop it from list
    img1 = list_image[0]
    list_image.pop(0)
    # append all images and save as pdf
    img1.save(f"{name}.pdf",save_all=True, append_images=imagelist)

def main():
    # List directory
    directory = os.listdir(".")
    for i in directory:
        # if directory start with 'vol' iterate through it
        if i.find("vol") != -1:
            path = []
            sub_dir = os.listdir(i)
            # for each subdirectory
            for j in sub_dir:
                files = os.listdir(f"{i}/{j}")
                for k in files:
                    # if file ends with jpg or png append to list
                    if k.endswith((".jpg", ".JPG", ".png", ".PNG")):
                        path.append(f"{i}/{j}/{k}")
            # merge list into one pdf
            merge_into_pdf(path, i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You may need ! pip install pillow and ! pip install image and finally ! pip install img2pdf to run the above code smoothly